# Please clarify Soulknife's Blade Skill Multiple Throw?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

Please clarify [Soulknife's](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/#TOC-Blade-Skills) [Blade Skill Multiple Throw](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/blade-skills/#Multiple_Throw)?

> Multiple Throw: The soulknife can throw a number of mind blades per round equal to the number of melee attacks she could make. A soulknife must be at least 14th level to choose this blade skill.

Does mean you are only allowed to throw one mind blade per round of combat unless you have this Blade Skill and be Lv14 Soulknife and how does effect having [Twin Strike Blade Skill](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/blade-skills/#Twin_Strike) at Lv8?

> Twin Strike: When making a single standard attack and wielding two mind blades, the soulknife may attack with both of her mind blades at the normal penalties for two-weapon fighting. She may also utilize this ability when making attacks of opportunity, but not for any other special attacks, unless specifically stated otherwise. The soulknife must be at least 8th level to choose this blade skill.

Answer (score 2):

A soulknife normally takes a move action to [form one or two mind blades](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/#TOC-Form-Mind-Blade-Su-), and a mind blade can be [thrown](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/#TOC-Throw-Mind-Blade). However, "[w]hether or not the attack hits, a thrown mind blade then dissipates." At level 5 the soulknife gets Quick Draw that says that she "may manifest her mind blade as a free action, though she may still only attempt to do so once per round (unless throwing the weapon multiple times using the Multiple Throw blade skill)."

Thus, a soulknife wielding a pair of mind blades can take a full-round action to make a full attack with those mind blades, and that full attack can include *both* two-weapon fighting *and* throwing the mind blades, but, before taking the blade skill [**Multiple Throw**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/blade-skills/#Multiple_Throw), a soul knife can't form more than two mind blades per round. Multiple Throw overcomes this limitation, allowing the soulknife to make full number iterative attacks with her thrown mind blades.

Essentially, the Multiple Throw blade skill allows the soulknife to create new mind blades when she normally couldn't and use them immediately for thrown weapon attacks.

There is no interaction between the blade skills Multiple Throw and [**Twin Strike**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/blade-skills/#Twin_Strike). If used to make two thrown weapon attacks, the Twin Strike blade skill simply leaves the soulknife emptyhanded afterward.